# Python delete row in numpy array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

I have a large numpy array (8 by 30000) and I want to delete some rows according to some criteria. This criteria is only applicable in one column.

Example:

```
>>> p = np.array([[0, 1, 3], [1 , 5, 6], [4, 3, 56], [1, 34, 4]])
>>> p
array([[ 0,  1,  3],
   [ 1,  5,  6],
   [ 4,  3, 56],
   [ 1, 34,  4]])
```

here I would like to remove every row in which the value of the 3rd column is >30, ie. here row 3.

As the array is pretty large, I'd like to avoid `for` loops. I thought of this:

```
>>> a[~(a>30).any(1), :]
array([[0, 1, 3],
   [1, 5, 6]])
```

But there, it obviously removes the two last rows. Any ideas on how to do that in a efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p = p[~(p[:,2] > 30)]
```

or (if your condition is easily inversible):

```
p = p[p[:,2] <= 30]
```

returns

```
array([[ 0,  1,  3],
       [ 1,  5,  6],
       [ 1, 34,  4]])
```

Comment: @Jolfulorc -- Welcome to SO! If this answer helped you find a solution to your problem, you should feel free to accept it (click the little check mark next to it).  This lets others know that your problem has been solved so they don't spend a lot of time trying to figure it out.